# Why does the initial p close automatically?

Tags: html, display

`p1` appears to be an empty `p` and the rest is displayed separately when I inspect in Google Chrome. Why would the initial automatically close? I've checked whether the tags are closed right.

```html
<p id=p1 style="display:none">
 <p>
  <b>You have French (8a) on:</b>
  <ul>
   <li>
    <b>Monday</b> at 09:45:00 for 01:30:00
   </li>
   <li>
    <b>Thursday</b> at 12:00:00 for 01:30:00
   </li>
  </ul> and have a grade of 8/10.
 </p>
</p>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you cant use Paragraph for this type .
you can't nest things on P tag .
for example :

```
<p>i love chease</p>
```

so if you want to solve your problem . use Div

```html
<div id="p1" style="display:none;">
    <div>
        <b>You have French (8a) on:</b>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <b>Monday</b> at 09:45:00 for 01:30:00
            </li>
            <li>
                <b>Thursday</b> at 12:00:00 for 01:30:00
            </li>
        </ul> and have a grade of 8/10.
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wrong explanation. You can’t nest `<p>` tags.